# Image Grab Failed by Minimizing(or Closing) Remote Connection or Running too Many Times

Tags: python, image, screenshot, remote-server, pyautogui

I wrote a code, and I want to run it in a server. I use windows remote connection for connecting to this server. I have some problems.

1. I want to run Image Grab for taking screenshot's too many times(approximately 3 times each second) for 7 hours. I use `Pyautogui` package for screenshot. But when this program ran, an error occurred and program stops execution.

   `IOError: screen grab failed`

I used other packages(like python `ImageGrab()`) also, but it occurred again.

2. When I want to close or minimize my remote connection, that error occurred again. So I could not close or minimize remote windows.

Code: I summarized my code for better understanding.

```
import pyautogui
import time
i=0
while(True):#i<200000
    im=pyautogui.screenshot()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    i+=1
    """"""
    """Main Algorithm"""
```

**Comment:** I use `Pyautogui` package because it take screenshots too fast.

Comment: Did the error occurred during the execution of your script, or at the beginning of  execution.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I'm weak in English.

Comment: You need to share the code you use to help finding the solution

Comment: Ok. I'll share it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @VasuDeo.S . This error have happened casually. For example it maybe fall into error after 16000 screenshots or after 250000 screenshots. it doesn't have a single value.

Comment: Do you have a auto windows lockdown or screen timeout enabled?

Comment: I disabled lock screen,   two of us use this server and sometimes by remoting more than two people, out connection will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too tries for how to handle this error I found solution:
Since Our error was `IOError: screen grab failed`

I wrote a `try Exception`:

```
import pyautogui
import time
i=0
while(True):#i<200000
    try:
        im=pyautogui.screenshot()
        time.sleep(0.3)
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(1)
        im=pyautogui.screenshot()
    i+=1
    """"""
    """Main Algorithm"""
```

I added one second time sleep, for occurring exception. I don't know why, but by setting less than one second time sleep I saw that error again.